# access current revision number

Tags: python, version-control, mercurial, python-3.x, tortoisehg

Every time my Python application is run, it creates a log. I want to include in that log the revision number of the code that was executed. How can I do that?

I use Python 3.2, Windows TortoiseHg 2.2.2 with Mercurial 2.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using setuptools to distribute your application/package, you can access the installed package version at run time using `pkg_resources.get_distribution("my_package").version`. However setuptools does not support automatic version tagging with mercurial revisions, so you will have to build your distributions with commands like:

```
python3 setup.py egg_info -b -$(hg heads --template "{node|short}" `hg branch`) sdist
```

or

```
python3 setup.py egg_info -b -$(hg heads --template "{node|short}" `hg branch`) setup
```

Comment: Actually, I don't distribute the app; I'm only running it on my own machine (calling `main.py` directly from the command line...)

Comment: If you have separate development/deployment paths (which is a very recommended approach anyway), you still can use setuptools for deployment. Otherwise the only option would be to create an autogenerated file which holds the current version and hook its generation to the post-commit script.

Comment: Should this go into `changegroup` or `commit` hook? And what operation would allow me to create a file named after (or containing inside it) the revision number?

Comment: That depends on your workflow. Probably you should hook both. You can access current commit id (or first commit from the group) through the environment variables and generate/update a file with a version number. See [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) for more details and hook examples.